# transit visa for UK required? layover time-14 hrs/ travel - india to vancouver/ valid canadian visa/ arriving in london on 20 aug and leaving 21

Tags: visas, air-travel, uk, india, airports

im going to travel from Hyderabad to Vancouver on 20th august, and will be passing through heathrow. My layover time being 14hrs, will I require a transit visa? I have a valid canadian study permit, but will be arriving at heathrow on 20th and leaving on 21st. I do not have any intention to go out for a visit and also don't need to go through immigration. please help, i dont have much time!

Comment: You don't need to worry about this.

Answer (score -1):

The gov.uk website will have more information on this. As long as you don't plan on leaving the airport you should be considered as transit. Heathrow has a lot of shops and restaurants you can go to during your layover.

Comment: Hi Josh, if you're going to indicate a site that has the info, perhaps you could link to the relevant page.  Otherwise they just have to go on your word, or go hunting through a very large website :/

Comment: I assume he means the site referenced in the duplicate.